# ACCESS/SQL - Create query that combines all unique records from multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, union

I have three tables with only one common field [Asset].

One table [tblAssets] contains all fields that I want.

However, I would like to check the other two tables and add any [Asset] that does not appear in the first table.

This should result in a new record containing only [Asset] and the rest of the fields blank.

My current code is as follows:

```
SELECT *, "Assets" AS [Source]
FROM [tblAssets]
UNION SELECT "BOM", [Asset], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM [tblBOM]
UNION SELECT "WO", [Asset], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM [tblWO];
```

This adds records as expected, but does not remove duplicates due to the entire record not being a duplicate.

I suspect there are other methods to tackle this, such as Append queries with certain conditions.

To clarify, I want a full list of all [Asset] that appear within multiple data sources but ONLY the rest of the fields that appear in the [Assets] table.

Sample Data:

tblAssets -

```
       Asset  Type  Unit  
         P1     2    1
         M1     1    2
```

tblBOM -

```
       Comp   Asset  Qty
         1      P1     1
         2      P2     2
```

tblWO -

```
         WO    Asset  Cost
         1      P1     100
         2      C1     200
```

Current Output

```
        Source  Asset  Type   Unit  
        Assets   P1     2       1    
        Assets   M1     1       2   
         BOM     P1                  
         BOM     P2                 
         WO      P1                
         WO      C1
```

Desired Output

```
        Source  Asset  Type   Unit 
        Assets   P1     2       1    
        Assets   M1     1       2                 
         BOM     P2                               
         WO      C1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Gordon Added, thanks

Comment: just use `where [Asset] not in (SELECT Asset from tblAssets)` and similar for the other 2 tables.

Comment: @xQbert thanks for your response, I just tried this and resulted in only records from the tblAsset. I am relatively new to SQL so I may have gotten the syntax or placement wrong. To clarify, I should enter the code you suggested after the "FROM [tblBOM]" and "FROM [tblWO]"? Also, what if the case that an [Asset] appears in both tblBOM and tblWO? In this case, I don't care what appears in [Source], just want the record to appear.

Comment: What column is source to go into you have it in the begining on the 2 unions and at the end on the asset.  can't do that.

Comment: @xQbert the Source field is an added field via AS, which tells me which data source the record is being added from. For some reason when I add the field via AS in the asset it creates the field in the first column rather than after the other fields. To alleviate this I just changed the unions to match. Any thoughts on why AS creates field in first column would be appreciated!

Comment: Strange behavior for sure.  The order of the columns in your select should not be altered by the engine.  Perhaps alias table assets to A and use A.* when selecting the fields, or spell out each field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select from tables `tblBOM` and `tblWO` all the distinct values of `Asset` that don't exist in table `tblAssets`:

```
SELECT "Assets" AS [Source], * FROM [tblAssets]
UNION 
SELECT "BOM" AS [Source], [Asset], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM [tblBOM]
WHERE [Asset] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Asset] FROM [tblAssets])
UNION 
SELECT "WO" AS [Source], [Asset], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM [tblWO]
WHERE [Asset] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Asset] FROM [tblAssets])
```

Answer (score 0):

- Include everything from assets:
- and only those from tblBOM not in assets and not in tblWO
- and all those from tblWO not in Assets

.

```
SELECT "Assets" AS [Source], A.*
FROM [tblAssets] A
UNION SELECT "BOM", [Asset], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM [tblBOM]
WHERE [Asset] not in (SELECT Asset FROM tblAssets)
  and [Asset] not in (SELECT ASSET FROM [tblWO])
UNION SELECT "WO", [Asset], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM [tblWO]
WHERE [Asset] not in (SELECT Asset FROM tblAssets)
```

Comment: Ok How june?  my firewall prevent me from posting the word Union?  (thanks regardless)

Comment: No idea. I used to see that happen on another forum site.